# How Can I show the Date Picker if I Click the Icon?

Tags: html, date, datepicker, icons

When I click the Icon, the date-picker doesn't show. Here's my code. Thanks In Advance.

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="dateOfBirth"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"
             rv-value="applicant:personalInformation:dateOfBirth | date"
             type="text" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="wizard-step-1">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="entypo-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the script to ur code and include the jquery plugins. like this

```js
    $(function () { 
  $('#dateOfBirth').datetimepicker({
format: 'L'
});});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="dateOfBirth"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"
             rv-value="applicant:personalInformation:dateOfBirth | date"
             type="text" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="wizard-step-1">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="entypo-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: more datepicker examples check on this [link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

this working fine. check this

```js
    $(function () { 
  $('#dateOfBirth').datetimepicker({
format: 'L'
});});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="dateOfBirth"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"
             rv-value="applicant:personalInformation:dateOfBirth | date"
             type="text" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="wizard-step-1">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="entypo-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: date format i am given here "L" that means Month numeral, day of month, year.

Comment: for in icon click you have to give id  inside div   <div class="input-group" id="dateOfBirth">